# SSAO shader not working as intended

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl, voxel, ssao

I'm making a voxel game in LWJGL and figured out how to implement an SSAO shader but it's not looking how I expected it too. Looking at blocks from far away is fine, I can see a gradient-shadow outline of the block. But up close, that gradient-shadow goes away just leaving me with the color of the block(plus another simple shader I made to give each block side a different shade).

Here's what the game looks like from different distances:
https://github.com/ninthworld/GreedyMeshing/raw/master/screenshot1.png
https://github.com/ninthworld/GreedyMeshing/raw/master/screenshot2.png

Here's what I expected it to look like:
https://github.com/ninthworld/GreedyMeshing/raw/master/screenshot3.png

And this is what my SSAO.frag shader code looks like:

```
uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

uniform vec2 camerarange;
uniform vec2 screensize;

float readDepth( in vec2 coord ) {
    return (2.0 * camerarange.x) / (camerarange.y + camerarange.x - texture2D( texture0, coord ).x * (camerarange.y - camerarange.x));  
}


void main(void)
{   
    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    //vec2 texCoord = texture2D(texture0, gl_TexCoord[0].st).xy;
    //vec3 texColor = texture2D(texture1, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;

    float depth = readDepth( texCoord );
    float d;

    float pw = 1.0 / screensize.x;
    float ph = 1.0 / screensize.y;

    float aoCap = 0.45;

    float ao = 0.0;

    float aoMultiplier=1000.0;

    float depthTolerance = 0.008;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    pw*=2.0;
    ph*=2.0;
    aoMultiplier/=2.0;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    pw*=2.0;
    ph*=2.0;
    aoMultiplier/=2.0;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    pw*=2.0;
    ph*=2.0;
    aoMultiplier/=2.0;

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y+ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x+pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    d=readDepth( vec2(texCoord.x-pw,texCoord.y-ph));
    ao+=min(aoCap,max(0.0,depth-d-depthTolerance) * aoMultiplier);

    ao/=16.0;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0-ao) * texture2D(texture1, texCoord);
}
```

The two samplers are each receiving a texture I created from the GL_RGBA and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and then gl_FragColor is drawing to a 2D plane that takes up the screen.

If looking at more of the code would help, here's the github page https://github.com/ninthworld/GreedyMeshing

Comment: are you still having problem? the thread is a bit old